# How to handle not enough permissions in php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling, user-permissions

I've came accross a strange issue while working with MySQL with PHP and mysqli object. I have user, which I use to connect to MySQL and that user has enough permissions to work with specific database. All works fine.

But I am trying to get list of all databases. User doesn't have permissions for that. Obviously I can't see any results of my query. But the strange thing is that I also have nothing in $mysqli->errno, $mysqli->error (no permission denied or any kind of error!) and my $result is not FALSE. So in this situation everything looks as if the query was executed fine and there are no databases on the server (of course this is not true).

The question is not about how to give the user rights to execute SHOW DATABASES.. The question is: Why I don't see any errors, while user lacks permissions to execute specific query? And further, how to properly handle such situation?

I use this code and it doesn't handle the situation, since $result is not FALSE - it is just normal $result, but with empty rows

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW DATABASES");
if($result === FALSE){
    echo 'We've got MySQL error! '.$mysqli->errno.':'.$mysqli->error);
}
```

Appreciate any kind of suggections!

Comment: As documented under [SHOW DATABASES Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-databases.html), "*you see only those databases for which you have some kind of privilege*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo! Thanks eggyal!

My user sees only databases he has access to. I thought, that he will get error if he has no permissions to list databases on the server. Now everything is clear!